# Is there a way for spark context to read an executable file from hdfs?

Tags: apache-spark

I have put an executable file into HDFS. I would like to read it on each Spark worker in order to run the output of RDD through it. Is there a way to do that? This is similar to sc.addFile("program"). Unfortunately sc.addFile doesn't work, since the following line:

```
JavaRDD<String> output = data.pipe("Program"):
```

produces the following exception:

```
TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3,  compute14.dev):
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Program": error=2, No  such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PipedRDD.compute(PipedRDD.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  It is happening to me too...

Comment: It is happening to me too... please help!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `rdd.pipe()` is the path to an executable program in the local file system, so I think one thing you could definitely do is to read the program from HDFS, write it to some location in the local file system (on each executor!) and then use `rdd.pipe()`.

In particular, I think you could use `binaryFiles()` to load the data from HDFS, then `collect()` it on the executor, store it in a broadcast variable and then do your processing like

```
rdd.foreachPartition(_ => /* write contents of broadcast variable
                             to some local file */ )
rdd.pipe( /* path of that local file */ )
```

Comment: But, doesn't sc.addFile("./Program") make a copy of the Program to each executor?

Comment: Ah, you may be right; I understood the `addFile()` function differently.The doc says: "To access the file in Spark jobs, use `SparkFiles.get(fileName)` to find its download location." I think that's what you have to pass in to `rdd.pipe()`. Although that would imply that the path is the same on all nodes and the driver knows about it...?

Comment: That's actually the root of my question. addFile("Program") doesn't seem to make a copy of Program to every executor node. Since pipe(SparkFiles.get("Program") can't find the Program on some of the executor nodes.

Comment: Can you check whether `rdd.foreachPartition(_ => SparkFiles.get("Program"))` outputs the same path on every executor?